# Process as string for each item in dataframe or list in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, zipcode

I'm trying something very simple on python.

`zips = sempmme['Zip code'].unique()`

I want to apply `zipcode.isequal('12345')` for each `zips` but I'm not sure how to do it in pythonic efficient way.

I tried 'zipcode.isequal(lambda x: x in zips)' and even for loop but I can't seem to get it.

```
for i in range(0, len(zips)):
    #print(zips[i])
    cities[i] = zipcode.isequal("" + zips[i])
```

It shows 'isequal() can only take string'. Needless to say, this is the first time I'm coding in Python. And figured the best way to learn is to take a project and figure it out.

EDIt:

output of `repr(zips)`:

```
"array([u'25404', u'265056555', u'251772049', u'25177', u'26508', u'25262',\n       u'26554', u'265053816', u'154741359', u'15461', u'26250',\n       u'262413392', u'25443', u'26505', u'258809366', u'217331141',\n       u'26757', u'26201', u'25419', u'25427', u'25401', u'26003',\n       u'25428', u'26150', u'268479803', u'24426', u' ', u'25813',\n       u'253099769', u'22603', u'25174', u'25984', u'25430', u'25438',\n       u'268360008', u'254356541', u'26170', u'25971', u'24622', u'24986',\n       u'26847', u'24957', u'25963', u'25064', u'260039425', u'25526',\n       u'25523', u'26452', u'25143', u'26301', u'25285', u'26104',\n       u'25951', u'25206', u'24740', u'252137436', u'25420', u'26330',\n       u'24701', u'25309', u'25304', u'26408', u'25564', u'26753',\n       u'15349', u'45767', u'25213', u'25168', u'25302', u'24931',\n       u'26623', u'25704', u'26362', u'24966', u'250641730', u'26415',\n       u'25130', u'26134', u'25413', u'26101', u'25193', u'26354',\n       u'260031309', u'26651', u'24954', u'26180', u'256700145', u'26033',\n       u'26444', u'25661', u'26555', u'264521704', u'25111', u'25043',\n       u'26278', u'25560', u'25181', u'25854', u'259210233', u'24874',\n       u'26181', u'24963', u'254381574', u'25557', u'26203', u'26836',\n       u'255109768', u'25035', u'25214', u'26726', u'25132', u'25411',\n       u'24853', u'26750', u'25071', u'25913', u'26374', u'25110',\n       u'24901', u'25843', u'25880', u'26610', u'26456', u'41514',\n       u'26684', u'25541', u'25311', u'26431', u'26241', u'26541',\n       u'25162', u'25312', u'24801', u'26159', u'25239', u'255269325',\n       u'26293', u'249460055', u'25149', u'26743', u'261871112', u'25315',\n       u'25570', u'25123', u'254300341', u'25705', u'25421', u'24747',\n       u'261709789', u'26438', u'26448', u'263011836', u'26041', u'25248',\n       u'24739', u'25125', u'25510', u'26531', u'251860464', u'263690126',\n       u'26205', u'25678', u'251238805', u'25320', u'249707005', u'25414',\n       u'26133', u'263850384', u'26501', u'25405', u'25882', u'25244',\n       u'25504', u'25635', u'24868', u'26143', u'25313', u'45769',\n       u'24870', u'25508', u'26323', u'24832', u'25202', u'26451',\n       u'25637', u'26288', u'26656', u'25670', u'25550', u'25059',\n       u'456197853', u'249011225', u'25303', u'45680', u'26155', u'25002',\n       u'25387', u'251771047', u'263230278', u'256250601', u'246051700',\n       u'25045', u'25085', u'25011', u'25136', u'26405', u'25241',\n       u'26070', u'25075', u'259181310', u'26105', u'25253', u'25275',\n       u'24811', u'26287', u'25669', u'25159', u'26833', u'26378',\n       u'24850', u'45760', u'26519', u'22802', u'25039', u'25403',\n       u'26425', u'25625', u'254254109', u'253099281', u'258821226',\n       u'255609701', u'252761627', u'25545', u'26546', u'25674',\n       u'255701081', u'25547', u'257021403', u'25555', u'25113',\n       u'255609730', u'255089543', u'25909', u'250489721', u'25958',\n       u'25831', u'25825', u'25701', u'258479621', u'267630283', u'26588',\n       u'24945', u'254280359', u'257029632', u'254253549', u'24869',\n       u'25203', u'24847', u'248440000', u'25425', u'24614', u'26807',\n       u'253069761', u'28104', u'26525', u'24910', u'25361', u'259813804',\n       u'24808', u'253027228', u'26601', u'25801', u'25702', u'26208',\n       u'255249621', u'25652', u'25033', u'26416', u'24712', u'25444',\n       u'32707', u'259621513', u'25644', u'26034', u'262419617', u'25917',\n       u'26062', u'25169', u'24731', u'254434652', u'25314', u'24620',\n       u'75092', u'25306', u'26385'], dtype=object)"
```

Comment: provide examples of properly using `zipcode.isequal` and your failed attempts.

Comment: "I keep getting errors". What errors? Please list them.

Comment: Please check the edited question. I was typing questions from my mobile device which I accidentally posted while scrolling down before I could read the question.

Comment: Is this python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: using Spyder for Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your goal in "applying `zipcode.isequal` for each `zips`"...

To return a list where each element is the return value of `zipcode.isequal()` of the elements in zips:

```
cities = [zipcode.isequal(str(zip)) for zip in zips]
```

or return a list containing the elements in zips for which `zipcode.isequal()` returns true:

```
cities = [zip for zip in zips if zipcode.isequal(str(zip))]
```

Edit: Given that `zips` does not consist entirely of numeric strings, you probably need to do an additional filter on either one:

```
cities = [zipcode.isequal(str(zip)) for zip in zips if zip.isdigit()]
cities = [zip for zip in zips if zip.isdigit() and zipcode.isequal(str(zip))]
```

Comment: I still get the same error: `TypeError: zipcode should be a string` which is referring to `zip` for the 1st one. And I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '` for the second one

Comment: Please add the output of `repr(zips)` to your question.

Comment: When you received the errors for the examples in this answer, did you use the `zipcode.isequal(str(zip))` versions?

Comment: It seems like zipcode.isequal() expects string as in '12345', but the code is providing `u'12345' which is causing the error. Is there a way to remove 'u' from the string?

Comment: yes I did try `zipcode.isequal(str(zip))`. As mentioned in the first comment, the error I received was `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: that's what `str()` will do - translate from a unicode string to a non-unicode string.

Comment: one of the strings in `zips` is `u' '`.  You need to filter that out apparently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122949/discussion-between-j-earls-and-user1828605).

Comment: You're awesome. that's exactly what I needed. thanks for helping me through with this. Learnt a lot in this one.